# Show that $\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x, y)\, dy \, dx$ exists and equals zero.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $R = [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$, and let $f$ be the characteristic function of the set $S=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left\{ \frac{1}{2^n},\frac{3}{2^n},\cdots,\frac{2^n-1}{2^n} \right\}\times \left\{ \frac{1}{2^n},\frac{3}{2^n},\cdots,\frac{2^n-1}{2^n} \right\}\subseteq R$. Show that $\int_R f$ does not exist but that $\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x, y)\, dy \, dx$ exists and equals zero.

Showing that $\int_R f$ was simple. Now I am trying to show that $\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x, y)\, dy \, dx$ exists and equals zero.

So $\int_0^1 f(x, y)\, dy$ must exist and equal zero. But I'm not seeing how it does. To me it seems that the lower and upper integrals will always be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Define $A_n = \{1/2^n,3/2^n,\dots, (2^n-1)/2^n\}.$ Show that if $x\in [0,1],$ then $x$ can belong to at most one $A_n.$

Answer (score 0):

The set $S$ essentially consists of all points $(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}$ both of whose coordinates are "binary rationals". Since both $S$ and $R\setminus S$ are dense in $R$ the Riemann integral $\int_R f(x,y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)$ does **not exist**. As $S$ is countable, however, this integral exists as Lebesgue integral, and has the value $0$.

If $x_0\in[0,1]$ is not a binary rational then $f(x_0,y)=0$ at all points $(x_0,y)\in R$, hence $\int_0^1 f(x_0,y)\>dy=0$. But if $x_0\in[0,1]$ is a binary rational then $f(x_0,y)$ is $=1$ for a dense set of $y$ in $[0,1]$, and is $=0$ for a dense set of $y$ in $[0,1]$. It follows that the Riemann integral $\int_0^1 f(x_0,y)\>dy$ is **undefined** for such $x_0$.

Since the function $F(x):=\int_0^1 f(x,y)\>dy$ is undefined for a dense set of $x\in[0,1]$ it is **impossible** to consider the "outer" integral $\int_0^1 F(x)\>dx$.

Comment: Actually the set $S$ is missing most $(x,y)$ whose coordinates are binary rationals. For example, $(\{1/2\}\times [0,1]) \cap S$ only contains $(1/2,1/2).$ For all $x\in [0,1], (\{x\}\times [0,1]) \cap S$ is finite so there is no problem with any integral $dy$ (and they are all $0$). See my hint above.